# existe algum meio de fazer um redirecionamento caso não ache o banco de dados mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

estou com uma duvida, existe alguma forma de redirecionar o usuário para uma pagina 
404 caso não ache o banco de dados na conexão? 
segue meu codigo

```
$banco = 'qfood_'.$bdv;
            $conn1 = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', "$banco");



    $database_conn1 = "$banco";
            //verifica a conexão
            if ($conn1->connect_error) {
                die("Falha ao realizar a conexão: " . $conn1->connect_error);
    } else{

                $conn1->set_charset("utf8");
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$banco = 'qfood_'.$bdv;
            $conn1 = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', "$banco");



    $database_conn1 = "$banco";
            //verifica a conexão
            if ($conn1->connect_error) {
                http_response_code(404);
                include('my_404.php'); //forneça seu próprio HTML para o erro
                die();
    } else{

                $conn1->set_charset("utf8");
            }
    ?>
```

[Referencia http_response_code](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-response-code.php)